# Why is Uchiwa not able to monitor the datacenter on CentOS7?

Tags: centos7, redis, rabbitmq, sensu, uchiwa

[This post](http://ezandtheway.tumblr.com/post/121519465486/installing-sensu-on-centos-7) combined with [Install Sensu using YUM](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/platforms/sensu-on-rhel-centos) was used in order to install, configure and start Sensu and related services:

```
sudo yum install -y erlang && \
sudo rpm -Uvh http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.5.0/rabbitmq-server-3.5.0-1.noarch.rpm && \
sudo yum install -y redis && \
echo '[sensu]
name=sensu
baseurl=http://sensu.global.ssl.fastly.net/yum/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/sensu.repo && \
sudo yum install -y sensu && \
sudo yum install -y uchiwa && \
for s in rabbitmq-server redis.service sensu-server sensu-api uchiwa; do sudo systemctl restart $s; done && \
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost /sensu && \
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user sensu secret && \
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /sensu sensu ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

**Analysis**

- Navigating to :3000 shows the uchiwa dashboard and indicates `Connection error. Is the Sensu API running?`
- /var/log/sensu/sensu-api.log indicates

---

```
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T22:58:58.532905+0000","level":"warn","message":"config file does not exist or is not readable","file":"/etc/sensu/config.json"}
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T22:58:58.533069+0000","level":"warn","message":"ignoring config file","file":"/etc/sensu/config.json"}
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T22:58:58.533137+0000","level":"warn","message":"loading config files from directory","directory":"/etc/sensu/conf.d"}
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T22:58:58.712175+0000","level":"info","message":"api listening","protocol":"http","bind":"0.0.0.0","port":4567}
```

---

- The config.json does not seems to exist (`/etc/sensu/config.json: No such file or directory`)
- Downloading [the example config.json](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/configuration.html#new-config-file-on-disk-at-etcsensuconfigjson) and restarting the sensu-api did not solve the issue

---

```
{
  "rabbitmq": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "vhost": "/sensu",
    "user": "sensu",
    "password": "secret"
  },
  "redis": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 6379,
    "password": "secret"
  }
}
```

---

- the redis port is listening:

---

```
LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:6379                     *:*
```

---

- the rabbitmq port as well:

---

```
LISTEN     0      100          *:4567                     *:*
```

- Uchiwa cannot connect to the datacenters

---

```
{
  "sensu": [
    {
      "name": "Site 1",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 4567,
      "timeout": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Site 2",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 4567,
      "ssl": false,
      "path": "",
      "user": "",
      "pass": "",
      "timeout": 10
    }
  ],
  "uchiwa": {
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 3000,
    "refresh": 10
  }
}
```

---

```
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T23:34:32.990067621Z","level":"warn","message":"GET http://localhost:4567/stashes returned: 500 Internal Server Error"}
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T23:34:32.990102095Z","level":"warn","message":"Connection failed to the datacenter Site 1"}
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T23:34:32.990115588Z","level":"info","message":"Updating the datacenter Site 2"}
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T23:34:32.991462585Z","level":"warn","message":"GET http://localhost:4567/stashes returned: 500 Internal Server Error"}
{"timestamp":"2016-07-03T23:34:32.991492978Z","level":"warn","message":"Connection failed to the datacenter Site 2"}
```

---

- navigating to `<IPADDRESS>:4567` results in:

---

```
{"error":"redis and transport connections not initialized"}
```

---

- redis replies

---

```
sudo redis-cli ping
PONG
```

---

- redis password was set, but the issue persists

---

```
sudo redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> auth secret
OK
```

Comment: Changing the `redis.json` to use IPv4 only (i.e. `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` fixed it for me...) (But my `sensu-api.log` showed return code 500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concise**

The `sensu-client` seems to require a running `rabbitmq-server`. As this message broker did not seem to be running neither the `sensu-client` was able to start, nor the Uchiwa dashboard was able to monitor it.

**Verbose**

If the following error:

```
{"error":"redis and transport connections not initialized"}
```

is shown and `redis` is listening, please check that `rabbitmq` is running and check the rabbitmq port using rabbitmq-status:

```
sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server
```

*Example*

Today the above error was shown and when the rabbitmq port was checked it appeared that a certain port was not listening:

```
{listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}},
```

As SSL was configured, port 5671 should be configured in `/etc/rabbitmq.config`. Once the messagebroker server was restarted the ssl port `5671` started to listen and the issue was solved:

```
{listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"},{'amqp/ssl',5671,"::"}]},
```

my rabbitmq config is :

```
[
{rabbit, [ 
{ssl_listeners, [5671]},
{ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/cacert.pem"},
               {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/cert.pem"},
               {keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/key.pem"},
               {verify,verify_peer},
               {fail_if_no_peer_cert,true}]}
 ]}
  ].
```

Answer (score 3):

I first got RabbitMQ working when I set up correct SSL config in rabbitmq.json, it shows an example on the [Sensu Website](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/ssl.html#configure-sensu). 
After that it only said: "error": "not connected to redis"

I then got Redis working by changing from "localhost" in the sensu config to "127.0.0.1". 
Since Redis wasn't listening on IPv6 and "localhost" resolved both ::1 & 127.0.0.1 it didn't work properly.

This was a fresh install on Debian 8.

Answer (score -1):

Verify that sensu-api is configured and running.
On centos-7.x `systemctl status sensu-api`
to start the servive
`systemctl start sensu-api`